# How to find the point that gives the maximum value fast? Java or c++ code please

Tags: java, c++, math, geometry, linear-programming

I need a fast way to find maximum value when intervals are overlapping, unlike finding the point where got overlap the most, there is "order". I would have `int[][] data` that 2 values in `int[]`, where the first number is the center, the second number is the radius, the closer to the center, the larger the value at that point is going to be. For example, if I am given data like:

```
int[][] data = new int[][]{
{1, 1},
{3, 3},
{2, 4}};
```

Then on a number line, this is how it's going to looks like:

```
x axis: -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  
   1 1:       1 2 1  
   3 3:       1 2 3 4 3 2 1  
   2 4:  1  2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

So for the value of my point to be as large as possible, I need to pick the point x = 2, which gives a total value of 1 + 3 + 5 = 9, the largest possible value. It there a way to do it fast? Like time complexity of O(n) or O(nlogn)

Comment: Your example does not make sense. [1,1] is centered on the 0, [3,3] is centered on 2, but [2,4] is centered on 2? Huh?

Comment: @WJS the first line in the example is just the axis. `1 2 1` is the result of `1 1`, as in, at x=1, you get 2 points. if you're 1 away from that (x=0,x=2), you get 1 point. Except OP messed that bit up.

Comment: Sorry, I think I need more "spaces"

Comment: @lierwu I fixed it for you - is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes! I was just about to fix it!

Comment: wait, it's not 4 + 5 = 0 anymore

Comment: Not it is 5 + 3 +1 = 9

Comment: Wouldnt it be 1 + 3 + 5?

Comment: Ok, I think I'll change it again...

Comment: @WJS same thing. Are there any stated limits on the numbers. Any int, or the centerpoint is always between 0 and 20, and the radius always between 1 and 10, something like that?

Comment: No, the center and the radius are random, the radius is a positive integer. And no other limits.

Comment: This problem is easily expressed as a linear programming problem (technically mixed integer, but the problem design means that constraint is unnecessary). [COIN-OR](https://www.coin-or.org/) has FOSS solvers available, or you can implement the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) yourself, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: How do you use the simplex algorithm on this one? What is bound? And How do you set it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a simple O(n log n) algorithm.

Consider the value function v(x), and then consider its discrete derivative dv(x)=v(x)-v(x-1). Suppose you only have one interval, say `{3,3}`. dv(x) is 0 from -infinity to -1, then 1 from 0 to 3, then -1 from 4 to 6, then 0 from 7 to infinity. That is, the derivative changes by 1 "just after" -1, by -2 just after 3, and by 1 just after 6.

For n intervals, there are 3*n derivative changes (some of which may occur at the same point). So find the list of all derivative changes `(x,change)`, sort them by their x, and then just iterate through the set.

Behold:

```py
intervals = [(1,1), (3,3), (2,4)]

events = []
for mid, width in intervals:
    before_start = mid - width - 1
    at_end = mid + width
    events += [(before_start, 1), (mid, -2), (at_end, 1)]

events.sort()

prev_x = -1000
v = 0
dv = 0

best_v = -1000
best_x = None

for x, change in events:
    dx = x - prev_x
    v += dv * dx
    if v > best_v:
        best_v = v
        best_x = x
    dv += change
    prev_x = x

print best_x, best_v
```

And also the java code:

```java
 TreeMap<Integer, Integer> ts = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        
    for(int i = 0;i<cows.size();i++) {
        int index = cows.get(i)[0] - cows.get(i)[1];
        if(ts.containsKey(index)) {
            ts.replace(index, ts.get(index) + 1);
        }else {
            ts.put(index, 1);
        }
            
        index = cows.get(i)[0] + 1;
        if(ts.containsKey(index)) {
            ts.replace(index, ts.get(index) - 2);
        }else {
            ts.put(index, -2);
        }
            
        index = cows.get(i)[0] + cows.get(i)[1] + 2;
        if(ts.containsKey(index)) {
            ts.replace(index, ts.get(index) + 1);
        }else {
                ts.put(index, 1);
        }
    }
        
    int value = 0;
    int best = 0;
    int change = 0;
    int indexBefore = -100000000;
        
    while(ts.size() > 1) {
        int index = ts.firstKey();
        value += (ts.get(index) - indexBefore) * change;
        best = Math.max(value, best);
        change += ts.get(index);
        ts.remove(index);
    }
```

where `cows` is the data

Comment: Thanks! But what is v(x)? Second, why is it 0 from -infinity to -1? How did you get -1 and 0? Can you please explain it to me more clearly? Thanks!

Comment: And what is the mid and width in intervals? Can you please write it in for(declaration;condition;change) formation? Thanks!

Comment: v(x) is the total value at each x. It’s 0 from -infinity to 0 because no intervals overlap it so the total value is 0. Try this: find the total value at each point from -10 to 10 for one interval. Then see what the difference is between each value and the previous one. You should be able to see the pattern.

Comment: And mid and width are the two elements of your tuple describing an interval.

Comment: Ok! but why is it -infinity to 0? All my values are positive and can you please write a java form, please?

Comment: Consider: the value at 3 is 8. What’s the value at -3? What’s the value at -30? What’s the value at -300000000? They’re all 0.

Comment: Ok! I just misunderstand you, now I think I get it!

Comment: What is discrete derivative? I search it online, but got that it is Calculus stuff? How does Calculus have to do with programming?

Comment: As I said, it’s just the difference between the value at a point and the value at the previous point.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, a general `O(n log n)` or better would be tricky, probably solvable via linear programming, but that can get rather complex.

After a bit of wrangling, I think this can be solved via line intersections and summation of function (represented by line segment intersections). Basically, think of each as a triangle on top of a line. If the inputs are `(C,R)` The triangle is centered on `C` and has a radius of `R`. The points on the line are `C-R (value 0)`, `C (value R)` and `C+R (value 0)`. Each line segment of the triangle represents a value.

Consider any 2 such "triangles", the max value occurs in one of 2 places:

- The peak of one of the triangle
- The intersection point of the triangles or the point where the two triangles overall. Multiple triangles just mean more possible intersection points, sadly the number of possible intersections grows quadratically, so `O(N log N)` or better may be impossible with this method (unless some good optimizations are found), unless the number of intersections is `O(N)` or less.

To find all the intersection points, we can just use a standard algorithm for that, but we need to modify things in one specific way. We need to add a line that extends from each peak high enough so it would be higher than any line, so basically from (C,C) to `(C,Max_R)`. We then run the algorithm, output sensitive intersection finding algorithms are `O(N log N + k)` where `k` is the number of intersections. Sadly this can be as high as `O(N^2)` (consider the case `(1,100), (2,100),(3,100)...` and so on to `(50,100)`. Every line would intersect with every other line. Once you have the `O(N + K)` intersections. At every intersection, you can calculate the the value by summing the of all points within the queue. The running sum can be kept as a cached value so it only changes `O(K)` times, though that might not be posible, in which case it would `O(N*K)` instead. Making it it potentially `O(N^3)` (in the worst case for `K`) instead :(. Though that seems reasonable. For each intersection you need to sum up to `O(N)` lines to get the value for that point, though in practice, it would likely be better performance.

There are optimizations that could be done considering that you aim for the max and not just to find intersections. There are likely intersections not worth pursuing, however, I could also see a situation where it is so close you can't cut it down. Reminds me of convex hull. In many cases you can easily reduce 90% of the data, but there are cases where you see the worst case results (every point or almost every point is a hull point). For example, in practice there are certainly causes where you can be sure that the sum is going to be less than the current known max value.

Another optimization might be building an interval tree.

Comment: Hi! I like your answer, but I don't think I would need to calculate the intersection n^2 times since I can use a set. And I don't really get how do you use a queue to find the sum at that point. So, can you give a code that uses a queue? Just the part that finds the sum.

Comment: If you implement the bently ottman algorithm, you'll understand. It basically keeps a list of all line segments currently "in-play" you might say. For each intersection (which is a possible max value), you take a look at the line segments currently being considered and calculate the value at that intersection for line segment. Admittedly it's not a super straightforward solution. At each of the 2 events you calculate the max value. This is probably a better visual and explanation of the line sweep algorithm: http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html

Comment: As for not needing to calculate all the intersections, probably not. I could probably come up with an example where all O(n^2) intersections would need to be calculated. Keep in mind, in the most cases with random data, the number of intersections that exist is likely only O(N), hence why it's typically just referred to as `K` because without running the algorithm, you can't tell how many intersections there will be in advance. It's an output sensitive algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm

Comment: Hmmm, a bit more thought on this, and I think @Sneftel has the best answer. It uses a similar method as I suggested (priority queue), but without the intersection calculation. A bit more number crunching and it looks like the value at the intersections is going to the same if not lower than that the center points, as such there would be no benefit to calculating them.

Comment: Oh, ok, I get it. But, won't the memory be too large though?

Comment: For @Snettel's method? It's O(N) memory. Just need to create an array of size 3N and do an in-place sort (to avoid making it potentially 6N). Then you store the counters as single values (basically O(1) for those).

Comment: No, for your method, I wrote Snettel's method in java already.

Comment: Ah mine is probably excessive, not sure those intersections are needed anymore. As for memory, it is basically the same as the other method. It just has some extra work while loop to determine intersections and track those. Memory requirement is O(N + K), where K is the number of intersections, again potentially as high as O(N^2), but more likely O(N) on average. You can review the analysis here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm#Analysis You may want to look at the faster algorithms part. There are O(N + K) algorithms, but they are much more complex to implement.

Comment: Ok, I think I get! Although it is slower, I think that gives "all", which aren't bad.

Comment: Pretty much, though I'm not sure there's any benefit to calculating the intersections (debating on removing this answer), some number crunching suggests there may be no difference with or without them. Though I haven't thoroughly tested it.

Comment: I think you should not remove this. At lest I think it helps to "expend" thinks... Maybe.